# Generate a list of all possible combinations of a regular expression based string

Tags: regex, database, algorithm, programming-languages, combinatorics

This is not a straightforward "all possible combinations" question.

**EDIT: The regex is just a fixed length string with different combinations of alpha and non alphanumeric for each index...**

Given a regular expression of fixed length, what would be the fastest way of computing and storing all combinations in a database, speed of saving to database included. From the get go, given the regular expression to having any type of database of every combination?

What I did, successfully but ridiculously slow, was just create an array the length of the fixed length regular expression and each element contained every possible character at that position, I generated this with some script. And then just did a loopception on the array with an SQL Server connection open from start to finish inserting 10 possibilities at a time. It was extremely slow, we're talking a string of 7/8 characters with a maximum of 36 possibilities in any given location. It took a few days.

So, my question is given this problem what would be the best combination of technologies, languages and algorithm to accomplish this the quickest?

Comment: Are you saying you have a regex with just literals?

Comment: Generally, just use a character class in each character position. This way you only need 1 regex.

Comment: Similar to

/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][0-9|A|a|B|b|C|c|D|d]{8}/

Comment: I mean, this question is mostly about how would you go about getting every combination of that regex into a database...

Comment: Some example please. And what regex engine are you using? They all have minor differences

Comment: @JayCroghan I don't understand **1.** Why are you talking about regex? IMO this is a question about generating strings. **2.** Why would you store all combinations in a database? If it can be generated programmatically, there's no need to store it.

Comment: @Mariano I was using RegEx because I have a few RegEx's I needed to find all combinations too, none have wildcards to length is known. And for the second it was because the operations to be undertaken on them combined with the length of the combinations meant it would take a long time to process so saving to a database seemed proper so it could be stopped and resumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number of possible strings with length 8 and composed of 36 possible characters:

```
36^8 = 2821109907456 = 2,8 trillion
```

Generating that many strings in any way will take "considerable" time. Let's look at how long it will take to insert them into DB. Assuming a really good DB performance, we can take 20000 inserts/sec. In such a case the total insertion time is expected to be:

```
2,8 * 10^12 / 20000 = 140 million seconds
140 * 10^6 / (60*60*24) = 1620 days
```

So, this answers your question I guess: `1620 DAYS!`

Comment: Wow, that's not something that's possible. Back to the drawing board with me!

Comment: The question asks how to generate all possible combinations.. not how long it would take to generate them? This Q/A is useful for other people who are looking to generate combinations from a much simpler regex, such as `/foo{1,10}/`